# Glassfish deploy different war instance overwrites former

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy the same war file multiple times for different people, we decided to avoid multi-tenancy because each client wants his database and his application separate from others.

So far what we do is create a separate connection pool and a JDBC resource in glassfish administration panel and edit persistence.xml and update persistence-unit to our own persistence.

Then in Netbeans we create a custom war going into properties → build → packaging → war and setting a different war filename, then we edit properties → build → run → context path → and set our context name and finally we replace in web.xml → our name.

What happens is that sometimes our deployed wars overwrite a former one with a different name!
I feel like we are almost there but miss a small detail.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's rather uncommon as a deployment technic, because if you have to change something in the application (bug correction, improvement, ...) you will have to manually redeploy all your wars with the risk of mistakes. If think that you should use a script language like python or ruby to automate your deployments.

First reflexion :

- a configuration file containing one line per instance with all its parameters
- a python or ruby (or ... use you prefered script engine) script that goes through that config file and

  - makes config changes in the sources
  - build the war using `ant` or `maven`
  - deploy to the production server

Immediate improvements :

- allows for regeneration for all wars or simply some (id given as parameter)
- use a temporary directory for doing all that stuff (copy from your dev directory, but do not modify it)
- and all that you need and I didn't think about ...

But keep in mind that even with the traditional approach (one single war, one database) if the application has been designed with that objectif (still traditional way) each user can see only its own data.